# Will a diamond break if I hit it with a hammer

Tags: condensed-matter, stress-strain, matter, diamond

I was having this discussion with my friend about the hardness of diamonds. I would like to know if a diamond will break or not if hit with a hammer.

Different sources across the internet mention different things. Some say it will and some say it won't if it is real. However, Wikipedia says that it will break.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond

I just want to confirm if it will break.

Comment: Everything breaks if you hit it hard enough with the right hammer

Comment: If you hit it very hard, will it become very hot and burn?

Comment: @DirkBruere I mean a normal hammer.

Comment: A normal hammer hitting at 10 km/s? That will still break every known chemically bonded material.

Comment: @DirkBruere I think you mean 10 m/s.

Comment: No, 10 km/s. There are plenty of materials that will shrug off 10 m/s

Comment: I'm flabbergasted that a naive, easily researched question like this got any upvotes.  What's going on?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Me too. I was afraid that this might get flagged. The only reason I asked this was because I got different answer from different sources and I was just trying to confirm the fact. I don't mind deleting the question.

Comment: @luming Actually, if you have that kind of power(Joking) then it might. But, not sure since the hammer may burn before it even strikes the diamond with the kind of strength and force I am imagining. Any help,anyone?

Comment: @Yashbhatt Actually, this question's answer was in the wikipedia page you gave me. I suggest you see that. No need to delete question. It may help someone. Just telling you if you are interested.

Comment: @AmeyShukla I know the answer was on that page. But I got different answers from other sites and so was just confirming.

Answer (score 7):

The link you provided already had enough information. Well, unlike hardness, which denotes only resistance to scratching, diamond's toughness or tenacity is only fair to good.

That is, it is easily breakable by a hammer. The toughness of diamond is about  2.0 MPa which is good compared to other gemstones, but poor compared to most engineering materials.

So if I take a  hammer and hit a hammer hard, yeah that's gonna break. Diamond is hard, I agree but it's not unbreakable.

I'll roll up a little from comments, a interesting thing:

**A normal hammer hitting at 10 km/s? That will still break every known chemically bonded material. –  Dirk Bruere**

Answer (score 1):

You're probably misled by the usual form factor of diamonds.

Let's first think about a common material that's easy to break: glass. Think about a glass window pane and a glass marble. I think you'll intuitively say that it's a lot easier to break the window. But what if you'd put the marble on a concrete floor and hit it with a hammer? You'd crush the marble.

The reason for this unintuitive behavior is that applying a force to an object generally will accelerate that object. But the atoms of an object can only transfer a very small amount of force to other atoms. If you have apply force locally and there are not enough atoms to distribute that force over, they'll break the bonds with their neighbours. If that happens on a macroscopic scale, the object breaks.

Back to diamonds. They're generally small objects and typically not made in a flat form. If you hit it, *usually* the forces do not need to be transferred over large distances, and they're quite possibly applied to a significant fraction of the surface of the diamond (especially since diamond is quite hard and can easily leave a diamond-shaped dent in metal). Therefore, many of the atoms are accelerated together, which makes it less likely to break.